# Hive with Tez: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

Environment: Hadoop 2.7.3, hive-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT, Tez 0.8.4

My core-site.xml:

```
 <property>  
 <name>fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider</name>  
 <value>  
 org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider,   
 org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider,  
 com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider  
</value>  
<property>  
<name>fs.s3a.impl</name>  
<value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>  
<description></description>  
</property>  
<property>  
<name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>  
<value>GOODKEYVALUE</value>  
<description>AWS access key ID. Omit for Role-based authentication.       </description>  
</property>  
<property>  
<name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>  
<value>SECRETKEYVALUE</value>  
<description>AWS secret key. Omit for Role-based authentication.</description>  
</property>
```

I can access the s3a uri correctly  from hadoop command line. I can create external table and a command like:

```
create external table mytable(a string, b string) location 's3a://mybucket/myfolder/';  
select * from mytable limit 20;
```

executes correctly, but

```
select count(*) from mytable;
```

fails with:

```
Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1489267689011_0001_1_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1489267689011_0001_1_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:ROOT_INPUT_INIT_FAILURE, Vertex Input: url_sum_master initializer failed, vertex=vertex_1489267689011_0001_1_00 [Map 1], com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
        at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1110)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:759)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:723)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4194)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketRegionViaHeadRequest(AmazonS3Client.java:4949)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.fetchRegionFromCache(AmazonS3Client.java:4923)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4178)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4141)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1313)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:297)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:258)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.addSplitsForGroup(HiveInputFormat.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat.getSplits(HiveInputFormat.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.initialize(HiveSplitGenerator.java:196)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:278)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:269)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:269)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$InputInitializerCallable.call(RootInputInitializerManager.java:253)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1489267689011_0001_1_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in INITED state., Vertex vertex_1489267689011_0001_1_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:393)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:250)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:91)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:340)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:353)
```

The only way I can get it to work is if I use accesskey:secretkey in the uri itself, which is not possible for production code.

Thanks.

Comment: I should mention that: inside beeline, set fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider;  returns the three credentials providers listed in core-site.xml, so hiveserver2  is aware of the settings, but throws an exception  from SdkClientException class. My Hadoop was compiled with aws-java-sdk-1.11.93 .  The jackson jars are 2.6.6 and the httpclient  jar is 4.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you don't want to have the secrets in the URIs. Soon Hadoop will be telling you off for doing it, at some point it may stop it altogether.

Have a look in the troubleshooting S3a section of the [latest s3a docs](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/index.md).

If you are building Hadoop yourself (which your SDK version choice implies), then build Hadoop 2.8/2.9 and crank up debugging in the s3a package. There's a bit more logging of security there, but there's still a deliberate need to log less than you'd like, to keep those keys a secret.

you could also try setting the AWS environment variables on the destination machine. That doesn't fix the problem, but it could help in isolating it.

Comment: Thank you Steve: I have spent my weekend reading your answers - I really appreciate what you do. I no longer think it's a Hadoop issue though.  From Hadoop command line I can both read and write to s3a. I can also run Tez jars on S3:  

I think the issue is with hiveserver2 .  My first set of errors in Hive were related to Jackson jars version. Fixed that, the next were about httpclient jars (Hive 2.2SNAPSHOT use 4.5.2, Hadoop uses 4.2.5) .  It's not a Hadoop issue, if Tez can count words and put the results in an s3 bucket, then it can access one of the Credential Providers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by reverting to Hive2.1.1.

I assume the problem was jar versions incompatibility. My hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar was compiled using aws-java-sdk-1.11.93 - while Hive pulls in a version compiled with aws 1.7.4.

Comment: yeah, you can't mix AWS versions. I should add that to the troubleshooting section of the hadoop docs, Or you can, if you want file a bugrep...personal anecdotes always make for good reading.